# Blazor WASM Client calling a JavaScript library - Cannot work out how this works

Tags: javascript, blazor

I've spent 2 days going around in circles here and every time I solve one problem I run into another and Java/JavaScript is not my strength.

I have a Blazor Net 7 WASM app that draws a map using Syncfusion Map control.  I draw navigation lines between various points on the map and that works fine.  I want to enhance it so navigation lines by sea dont appear as straight lines, they follow the sea routes.

I have found the library https://github.com/johnx25bd/searoute which offers a JavaScript method of doing this but I cannot work out how to implement it correctly in my app.

I have installed the NPM file:

[npm file installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feGZm.png)

In a file called searoute.js which is in wwwroot/scripts/searoute.js I have the following function:

export function calculateWayPoints(originLatitude, originLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude) {

```
import searoute from 'searoute-js';
//const searoute = require('searoute-js');

var origin = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            originLongitude,
            originLatitude
        ]
    }
}

var destination = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            destinationLongitude,
            destinationLatitude
        ]
    }
}

var route = searoute(origin, destination);
```

}

The original example used 'require' which I couldn't get to work so I've commented it out above.  This isn't available in a browser environment if I have understood correctly.  It looks like import is the right way but I suspect this is wrong also.

The package.json is:

{
"version": "1.0.0",
"name": "asp.net",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"searoute-js": "0.1.0"
}
}

There is nothing in my index.html as I am using the following method to access the module:

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

```
 if (firstRender)
 {
     IJSObjectReference module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/searoute.js");

     await module.InvokeVoidAsync("calculateWayPoints", 43.3, 5.3, 31.2, 121, 8);
 }
```

}

Appreciate that I don't return a value from the JavaScript - I was taking components out to try and simplify things.

The error I am getting is:

[runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whBql.png)

Can anyone point in the right direction of how I can get this up and running.  I am way out of my comfort zone on this and I'm losing days on this and I suspect the solution is relatively simple.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
if (firstRender)
{
    IJSObjectReference module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", new { src = "./scripts/searoute.js", type = "module" });

    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("calculateWayPoints", 43.3, 5.3, 31.2, 121, 8);
}
```

```js
import searoute from 'https://esm.run/searoute-js';
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am now getting: 

Unhandled exception rendering component: Failed to resolve module specifier '[object Object]'

Do I need to install any other npm packages to get esm.run working?

Comment: strangely esm.run is an online module resolver seems like your compiler can't handle it try it `import searoute from 'searoute-js'`

Comment: it looks like this is the line that is causing the error:

IJSObjectReference module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", new { src = "./scripts/searoute.js", type = "module" });

if I comment out everything in the calculateWayPoints js function it still has an error which must mean its not the import sea route from xxxx line in the javascript

Comment: can you reproduce the minimal example. There are many compilers today (rpack, rolldown, vite, farm...) each compiler has a different solution and I don't have information about your compiler

Comment: I think I have worked it out now.  The library was only compatible with Node.js implementations so thats why it wasn't working on the web as I had expected.  appreciate your help thous Tachibana!